# Verifying that tasks are really async with AsyncDetector

Tags: c#, performance, async-await, task-parallel-library

Running tasks asynchronously can sometimes by tricky and no matter how careful I am, I sometimes forget some crucial part and my tasks run synchronously. I don't usually notice that until it's too late and  performance problems arise because of large amount of data not being processed in parallel/async. It's also difficult to write tests for it.

---

I thought maybe there is a way to detect if tasks are running asynchronously? My idea was to create the `AsyncDetector`. It works by running an internal `Stopwatch` and tracks the two timestamps per action: start & stop. The `BeginScope` method returns an `IDisposable` scope that when disposed adds both timestamps to an internal `ConcurrentBag`. Later when I want to check if tasks were really running async I group all async-scopes by their time intervals and check if any of them overlap. If they do, then I assume they ware running at the same time (at least for a moment).

```
class AsyncDetector
{
    private static readonly IEqualityComparer<(TimeSpan Start, TimeSpan End)> AsyncScopeComparer;
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<(TimeSpan Start, TimeSpan End)> _runtimes = new ConcurrentBag<(TimeSpan Start, TimeSpan End)>();
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    static AsyncDetector()
    {
        AsyncScopeComparer = AdHocEqualityComparer<(TimeSpan Start, TimeSpan End)>.CreateWithoutHashCode((left, right) =>
        {
            var a = left.Start.Ticks;
            var b = left.End.Ticks;
            var c = right.Start.Ticks;
            var d = right.End.Ticks;

            return
                (a <= c && c <= b) ||
                (a <= d && d <= b);
        });
    }

    public int MaxAsyncDegree
    {
        get
        {
            return
                _runtimes
                    .GroupBy(t => t, AsyncScopeComparer)
                    .Select(t => t.Count())
                    .Max();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> AllAsyncDegrees
    {
        get
        {
            return
                _runtimes
                    .GroupBy(t => t, AsyncScopeComparer)
                    .Select(t => t.Count());
        }
    }

    public int AsyncGroupCount
    {
        get
        {
            return
                _runtimes
                    .GroupBy(t => t, AsyncScopeComparer).Count();
        }
    }

    public IDisposable BeignScope()
    {
        return new AsyncScope(this);
    }

    private object ToDump() => new { MaxAsyncDegree, AsyncGroupCount };

    private class AsyncScope : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan _start;
        private readonly AsyncDetector _asyncDetector;

        public AsyncScope(AsyncDetector asyncDetector)
        {
            _asyncDetector = asyncDetector;
            _start = _asyncDetector._stopwatch.Elapsed;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _asyncDetector._runtimes.Add((_start, _asyncDetector._stopwatch.Elapsed));
        }
    }
}
```

It calculates the overlap by checking the endpoints of each time interval:

```
 a-----b        - task1
     c-------d  - task2
```

In case someone wanted to run it, I add the `AdHocEqualityComparer` that the above class is using:

> ```
> public class AdHocEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
> {
>   private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _equals;
>   private readonly Func<T, int> _getHashCode;
>
>   private AdHocEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals, Func<T, int> getHashCode)
>   {
>       _equals = equals;
>       _getHashCode = getHashCode;
>   }
>
>   public static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateWithoutHashCode([NotNull] Func<T, T, bool> equals)
>   {
>       if (equals == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@equals));
>
>       return Create(equals, _ => 0);
>   }
>
>   public static IEqualityComparer<T> Create([NotNull] Func<T, T, bool> equals, [NotNull] Func<T, int> getHashCode)
>   {
>       if (equals == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(equals));
>       if (getHashCode == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getHashCode));
>
>       return new AdHocEqualityComparer<T>(equals, getHashCode);
>   }
>
>   public bool Equals(T x, T y)
>   {
>       if (ReferenceEquals(null, x)) return false;
>       if (ReferenceEquals(null, y)) return false;
>       if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
>       return _equals(x, y);
>   }
>
>   public int GetHashCode(T obj) => _getHashCode(obj);
> }
> ```

---

I had another implementation before the `AsyncDetector` that work with thread-ids but it wasn't reliable when working with only async. I post it for reference:

> ```
> class ParallelityDetector
> {
>   private readonly object _syncLock;
>   private readonly ObservableCollection<int> _threads;
>   private int _maxThreads = 1;
>
>   public ParallelityDetector()
>   {
>       _syncLock = new object();
>       _threads = new ObservableCollection<int>();
>       _threads.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
>       {
>           switch (e.Action)
>           {
>               case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
>                   _maxThreads = Math.Max(_maxThreads, _threads.Distinct().Count());
>                   break;
>           }
>       };
>   }
>
>   public int MaxThreadCount => _maxThreads;
>
>   public void Beign()
>   {
>       lock (_syncLock) _threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
>   }
>
>   public void End()
>   {
>       lock (_syncLock) _threads.RemoveAt(0);
>   }
> }
> ```

---

**Example**

The test code runs four different loops:

- `Parallel.ForEach`

and three different *styles* of `Task.WaitAll`:

- One without async, this one runs sequentially
- One with async and without limitations
- One with async but using a `SemaphoreSlim` to limit the degree of parallelism

The complete test code:

```
void Main()
{
    var count = 10;
    var delay = 500; // in milliseconds

    TestParallelForeach(count, delay);
    TestWaitAllWithoutAsync(count, delay);
    TestWaitAllWithAsync(count, delay);
    TestWaitAllWithAsyncAndSemaphoreSlim(count, delay);
}

private static void TestParallelForeach(int count, int delay)
{
    var asyncDetector = new AsyncDetector();

    Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, count), i =>
    {
        using (asyncDetector.BeignScope())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
            PrintThreadId(i);
        }
    });

    asyncDetector.Dump(nameof(TestParallelForeach));
}

private static void TestWaitAllWithoutAsync(int count, int delay)
{
    var asyncDetector = new AsyncDetector();

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => 
    {
        using (asyncDetector.BeignScope())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
            PrintThreadId(i);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    asyncDetector.Dump(nameof(TestWaitAllWithoutAsync));
}

private static void TestWaitAllWithAsync(int count, int delay)
{
    var asyncDetector = new AsyncDetector();

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (asyncDetector.BeignScope())
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            PrintThreadId(i);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    asyncDetector.Dump(nameof(TestWaitAllWithAsync));
}

private static void TestWaitAllWithAsyncAndSemaphoreSlim(int count, int delay)
{
    var asyncDetector = new AsyncDetector();

    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(Environment.ProcessorCount);

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        using (asyncDetector.BeignScope())
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            PrintThreadId(i);
        }
        semaphore.Release();
    }));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    asyncDetector.Dump(nameof(TestWaitAllWithAsyncAndSemaphoreSlim));
}

private static void PrintThreadId(int item)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item} [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]");
}
```

**Results**

As the output shows all cases has been correctly recognized by the `AsyncDetector`:

```
0 [10]
2 [13]
3 [12]
1 [11]
4 [7]
8 [13]
5 [11]
6 [10]
7 [12]
9 [7]


TestParallelForeach       

MaxAsyncDegree
5 

AsyncGroupCount
3 

---

0 [12]
1 [12]
2 [12]
3 [12]
4 [12]
5 [12]
6 [12]
7 [12]
8 [12]
9 [12]


TestWaitAllWithoutAsync       

MaxAsyncDegree
1 

AsyncGroupCount
10 

---

9 [10]
6 [10]
5 [10]
4 [10]
3 [10]
2 [10]
1 [10]
0 [10]
8 [7]
7 [11]


TestWaitAllWithAsync      

MaxAsyncDegree
10 

AsyncGroupCount
1 

---

2 [11]
0 [7]
1 [13]
3 [10]
6 [13]
4 [11]
5 [10]
7 [7]
8 [13]
9 [7]


TestWaitAllWithAsyncAndSemaphoreSlim

MaxAsyncDegree
4 

AsyncGroupCount
4
```

---

I'm not a thread/async expert so this implementation might not be the best one but can you think of anything better that would have the least performance/synchronization hit? I'd like this test to be as *invisible* as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `RelayComparer` name? It sounds more dotnetish :) It could be like this - 17 lines instead of 36 - and could be a way shorter if C# was reasonable :)

```
class RelayComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public RelayComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals)
        : this(equals, _ => 0)
    {
    }

    public RelayComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals, Func<T, int> getHashCode)
    {
        _equals = equals ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(equals));
        _getHashCode = getHashCode ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getHashCode));
    }

    readonly Func<T, T, bool> _equals; 
    readonly Func<T, int> _getHashCode;
    public bool Equals(T x, T y) => _equals(x, y);
    public int GetHashCode(T obj) => _getHashCode(obj);
}
```

Where `AsyncScope` might have disposing delegate injected to get rid of bidirectional dependency on `AsyncDetector`:

```
class AsyncScope : IDisposable
{
    public static readonly IEqualityComparer<AsyncScope> OverlappingComparer = 
        new RelayComparer<AsyncScope>((AsyncScope left, AsyncScope right) =>
        {
            var a = left.Start.Ticks;
            var b = left.End.Ticks;
            var c = right.Start.Ticks;
            var d = right.End.Ticks;
            return
                (a <= c && c <= b) ||
                (a <= d && d <= b);
        });

    public AsyncScope(IStopwatch stopwatch, Action<AsyncScope> dispose)
    {
        _stopwatch = stopwatch;
        _dispose = dispose;
        Start = _stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        End = _stopwatch.Elapsed;
        _dispose(this);
    }

    readonly IStopwatch _stopwatch;
    readonly Action<AsyncScope> _dispose;
    public TimeSpan Start { get; }
    public TimeSpan End { get; private set; } 
}
```

And the `AsyncDetector` could be twice shorter – please note testability:

```
public class AsyncDetector
{
    public AsyncDetector()
        : this(new SystemStopwatch())
    {
    }

    public AsyncDetector(IStopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        Runtimes = new ConcurrentBag<AsyncScope>();
        Stopwatch = stopwatch ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stopwatch));
        Stopwatch.Start();
    }

    ConcurrentBag<AsyncScope> Runtimes { get; } 
    IStopwatch Stopwatch { get; }

    public IDisposable BeignScope() =>
        new AsyncScope(Stopwatch, s => Runtimes.Add(s));

    public int MaxAsyncDegree => Runtimes
        .GroupBy(t => t, AsyncScope.OverlappingComparer)
        .Select(t => t.Count())
        .Max();

    public IEnumerable<int> AllAsyncDegrees => Runtimes
        .GroupBy(t => t, AsyncScope.OverlappingComparer)
        .Select(t => t.Count());

    public int AsyncGroupCount => Runtimes
        .GroupBy(t => t, AsyncScope.OverlappingComparer)
        .Count();
}
```

**UPDATE** I wish we could write the following:

```
class RelayComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public RelayComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals, Func<T, int> getHashCode)
    {
        Equals = equals ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(equals));
        GetHashCode = getHashCode ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getHashCode));
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y) { get; }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj) { get; }
}
```

Comment: This looks nice. I think I like the name `RelayComparer` better but I'm afraid it has one issue now that it's so short. It's not longer canonical and does not provide the three default comparisons `left, null`, `right, null`, `left, right` which is why I wrote it in the first place because I didn't want to write them everytime. I also like the idea of `AsyncScope` now holding the `Start` and `Stop` properties ;-)

Comment: Perhaps they are already designing something like the Property-Method hybrid? With all that functional and sugar stuff comming with each release this is quite possible.

Comment: Speaking about _I with I could..._ - I wish it was possible to write something like this: `.Select(i => {}).Using(asyncDetector.BeginScope())` so that I don't have to polute each `Action` with `using`... I need to do some experiments...