# Stopwatch dependency for unit-testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

My [`AsyncDetector`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180174/asyncdetector-are-my-tasks-really-running-async-parallel) is internally using a `Stopwatch` to calculate time intervals. Because of this hardcoded dependency I am not able to write good unit-tests for it. So I must be able to use my own timestamps that I can use for assertions.

To do this I defined the `IStopwatch` interface that is a simplified version of the `Stopwatch`. Some of the properties I never use and my inteface does not provide them.

```
public interface IStopwatch
{
    bool IsRunning { get; }
    TimeSpan Elapsed { get; }
    IStopwatch Start();
    IStopwatch Stop();
    IStopwatch Restart();
    IStopwatch Reset();
}
```

Its default implementation is using of course the original `Stopwatch` so I provide it just for reference:

> ```
> public class SystemStopwatch : IStopwatch
> {
>   private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;
>
>   public SystemStopwatch()
>   {
>       _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
>   }
>
>   public bool IsRunning => _stopwatch.IsRunning;
>
>   public TimeSpan Elapsed => _stopwatch.Elapsed;
>
>   public static IStopwatch StartNew()
>   {
>       return new SystemStopwatch().Start();
>   }
>
>   public IStopwatch Start()
>   {
>       _stopwatch.Start();
>       return this;
>   }
>
>   public IStopwatch Stop()
>   {
>       _stopwatch.Stop();
>       return this;
>   }
>
>   public IStopwatch Restart()
>   {
>       _stopwatch.Restart();
>       return this;
>   }
>
>   public IStopwatch Reset()
>   {
>       _stopwatch.Restart();
>       return this;
>   }
>
>   public override string ToString()
>   {
>       return _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
>   }
> }
> ```

More interesing is the `DebugStopwatch` that will enumerate my timestamps on each access to the `Elapsed` property or it'll throw if there are not enough of them:

```
public class DebugStopwatch : IStopwatch
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<TimeSpan> _timestamps;
    private TimeSpan? _lastElapsed;
    private IEnumerator<TimeSpan> _enumerator;

    public DebugStopwatch([NotNull] IEnumerable<TimeSpan> elapses)
    {
        _timestamps = elapses ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elapses));
    }

    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public TimeSpan Elapsed
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsRunning)
            {
                if (_enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return (_lastElapsed = _enumerator.Current).Value;
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException("You did not define enough timestamps.");
            }

            return _enumerator?.Current ?? _lastElapsed ?? TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
    }

    public static IStopwatch StartNew(IEnumerable<TimeSpan> elapses)
    {
        return new DebugStopwatch(elapses).Start();
    }

    public IStopwatch Start()
    {
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            return this;
        }
        _enumerator = _timestamps.GetEnumerator();
        IsRunning = true;
        return this;
    }

    public IStopwatch Stop()
    {
        IsRunning = false;
        return this;
    }

    public IStopwatch Restart()
    {
        Stop();
        Reset();
        Start();
        return this;
    }

    public IStopwatch Reset()
    {
        _enumerator = _timestamps.GetEnumerator();
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (_lastElapsed ?? TimeSpan.Zero).ToString();
    }
}
```

**Example** Using it is very easy. I just need to provide a collection or enumeration with timestamps:

```
void Main()
{

    var stopwatch = DebugStopwatch.StartNew(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i)));

    stopwatch.Dump();
    stopwatch.Dump();
    stopwatch.Dump();

    stopwatch.Stop().Dump(nameof(IStopwatch.Stop));
    stopwatch.Dump();
    stopwatch.Dump();

    stopwatch.Reset().Dump(nameof(IStopwatch.Reset));
    stopwatch.Dump();
    stopwatch.Dump();
}
```

---

What do you think of the `DebugStopwatch`? Would you change anything about it? If so, how would you improve it?

Comment: Your system stopwatch implementation calls `Restart()` in `Reset()`.

Comment: @eurotrash oops, crap, thx, I guess I hit re+tab too fast ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would not return IStopwatch from Start/Stop/etc. This IStopwatch is not an immutable Value Object, like String for example: it would be easier to set expectations by having just this:

```
public interface IStopwatch
{
    bool IsRunning { get; }
    TimeSpan Elapsed { get; }
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    void Restart();
    void Reset();
}
```

`SystemStopwatch` would be a way shorter:

```
class SystemStopwatch : IStopwatch
{
    Stopwatch Stopwatch { get; } = new Stopwatch();
    public bool IsRunning => Stopwatch.IsRunning;
    public TimeSpan Elapsed => Stopwatch.Elapsed;
    public void Start() => Stopwatch.Start();
    public void Stop() => Stopwatch.Stop();
    public void Reset() => Stopwatch.Reset();
    public void Restart() => Stopwatch.Restart();
}
```

As for the `MockStopwatch` (sounds better than `Debug` one for me) – it could be a little bit shorter:

```
class MockStopwatch : IStopwatch
{
    public MockStopwatch(params TimeSpan[] intervals)
        : this(intervals.AsEnumerable())
    {
    }

    public MockStopwatch(IEnumerable<TimeSpan> intervals)
    {
        Interval = intervals
            .Prepend(TimeSpan.Zero)
            .ToList()
            .GetEnumerator();

        Reset();
    }

    IEnumerator<TimeSpan> Interval { get; }
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan Elapsed =>
        !IsRunning
        ? Interval.Current
        : Interval.MoveNext()
            ? Interval.Current
            : throw new InvalidOperationException("You did not define enough timestamps.");

    public void Start() => IsRunning = true;
    public void Stop() => IsRunning = false;

    public void Restart()
    {
        Stop();
        Reset();
        Start();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Interval.Reset();
        Interval.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Where you might need to define `Prepend` (.net core LINQ has one already):

```
static class PrependAppend
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item) =>
        Enumerable.Concat(new[] { item }, source);

    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item) =>
        Enumerable.Concat(source, new[] { item });
}
```

**Updated Elapsed**

What do you say about this one? Looks cleaner for me.

```
    public TimeSpan Elapsed => IsRunning ? NextElapsed : SameElapsed;
    TimeSpan SameElapsed => Interval.Current;
    TimeSpan NextElapsed => Interval.MoveNext() 
        ? Interval.Current 
        : throw new InvalidOperationException("You did not define enough timestamps.");
```

Comment: What a compression level ;-) With methods that return the object itself it's easier to do `return new MockStopwatch().Start()` inside of `StartNew()`.... `Interval.MoveNext()` - this won't work. This method always throws `NotImplementedException` - I came up with the same idea yesterday - sorry, forgot to mention it.

Comment: @t3chb0t 1) It is better to do not return anyway. Everyone will expect original object to stay unchanged and the modified copy to be returned... 2) I think you mean the `iterator.Reset()` method. This is why I invoke `ToList()` in the ctor - its iterator supports resetting.

Comment: Oh, sure, of course, `.Reset`. Ahhh, there, `.ToList()`, now I see it. I couldn't decide whether I should use a list or an ienumerable I case I have an endless enumerable... I still can't :-] but maybe I should create another type for that, `EndlessMockStopwatch`.

Comment: I agree that void methods look better. Returning `IStopwatch` form `Start` method makes it unclear whether it returns a new instance or not. However I would prefer original  `DebugStopwatch.Elapsed` implementation to nested ternary operators....

Comment: @NikitaB New `Elapsed` implementation reduces cyclomatic complexity of the method while requiring less state to preserve.

Comment: @DmitryNogin and I've got nothing against that. The only thing I do not like is nested ternaries. I would very much prefer your version if it had a couple of extra sets of `{}`. But that's just me. :)

Comment: I must say I'm not a fan of negative conditions like `!IsRunning`. That's why I use `if(IsRunning)`. The metrics might be _better_ the other way around but the positive version is for humans easier to read and understand.

Comment: @NikitaB What would you say about an Updated Elapsed version above?

Comment: Actually the `Elapsed` property of the .net Stopwatch violates the principle that properties should return values that are not likely to change on each access. The same with `NextElapsed`. I'll change the interface to make `Elapsed` a method.

Comment: Oh, and I made the debug-stopwatch disposable since it's using an enumeratator that is also one. Ok, Elapsed as a method looks stupid ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t `MockStopwatch` does not require it, as list enumerator disposing is not necessary.

Comment: Tell this to [@Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21337552/235671) or do you have any proof that it's not necessary? Who should I trust? :-D

Comment: In this concrete case - it is safe to do not dispose. Another example like that: [MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4274769/1219762)

Comment: Mhmmm... I don't know, this is a bad habit. I think I've found THE name for this thing, I'll call it the `PredictableStopwatch`, no test, no debug, no mock.

Comment: Crap, [`Dispose()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d3661cf752ff3f44) is empty... .net is sometimes really stupid.

Comment: @t3chb0t Well, rules do not replace understanding - I would not call it bad habit. This type just does not require disposing, so it is totally OK as long the enumerator is not injected. Also, I would define MockStopwatch in Unit Test project or Test API project only - such a name - "Mock" - perfectly fits their domain, there are a lot of stuff like that there usually.